# Flutter: Getting the warning "Expected to find fonts for " caused by missing "packages/cupertino_icons/CupertinoIcons"

Tags: flutter

When building an app for android I get the following message:

> Expected to find fonts for (MaterialIcons, packages/cupertino_icons/CupertinoIcons), but found (MaterialIcons). This usually means you are referring to font families in an IconData class but not including them in the assets section of your pubspec.yaml, are missing the package that would include them, or are missing "uses-material-design: true".

`"uses-material-design: true"` is in the `pubspec.yaml`

I am not using `CupertinoIcons` but some plugins used have them in their dependencies.

How can I get rid of the warning?

Comment: can u show ur pubspec.yaml file

Comment: I got the same issue, would think that it's caused by some dependency that relies on cupertino, but `flutter pub deps` didn't reveal any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the case of some of your dependencies using the cupertino icons without declaring a dependency on it.

In my case it was the [firebase_ui_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ui_auth) package which depends on [firebase_ui_shared](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ui_shared) and others. If you check the source code of these packages, they use CupertinoIcons at [several places](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/search?q=cupertinoIcons), but they only declare dependency in the [examples](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/search?q=cupertino_icons).

I'm afraid the only way to get rid of this warning is to add `cupertion_icons` to your own dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after adding `flutter_localizations`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

After that I used this package like this:

```
return MaterialApp(
  localizationsDelegates: GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegates,
  localeResolutionCallback: (locale, _) => locale ?? const Locale('en'),
  ...
);
```

And I also added widgets, something like these:

```
showAdaptiveDialog(...)

AlertDialog.adaptive(...)
```

I check: After I removed the dependency `flutter_localizations` and all related widgets, the build warning remained:

```
Expected to find fonts for (MaterialIcons, packages/simple_icons/SimpleIcons, packages/cupertino_icons/CupertinoIcons),
but found (MaterialIcons, packages/simple_icons/SimpleIcons). 

This usually means you are referring to font families in an IconData class but not including them in the assets section of your pubspec.yaml, 
are missing the package that would include them, or are missing "uses-material-design: true".
```

But the assembly was successful.

In your case, you should add the `cupertion_icons` dependency and use "Tree-shaking" flutter will take the icons you want. And by no means run the build with the `no-tree-shake-icons` flag, because this will add extra weight to your application.